# Why does program complain of too many commas?

Tags: c++

Here is my code, I have attached the screenshot of what output Zybooks expects, and what my output is. I am trying to get it to output exactly what Zybooks is asking, however something seams to be wrong. It is compiling though. Or maybe Zybooks is just being stupid?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string title;
    string col1;
    string col2;
    string val;
    int numCommas = 0;
    vector<string> stringData;
    vector<int> intData;

    cout << "Enter a title for the data:" << endl;
    getline(cin, title);
    cout << "You entered: " << title << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter the column 1 header:" << endl;
    getline(cin, col1);
    cout << "You entered: " << col1 << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter the column 2 header:" << endl;
    getline(cin, col2);
    cout << "You entered: " << col2 << endl << endl;

    while (1) {
        cout << "Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):" << endl;
        getline(cin, val);

        if (val == "-1") {
            break;
        }

        if (val.find(',') == -1) {
            cout << "Error: No comma in string." << endl << endl;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
                if (val.at(i) == ',') {
                    numCommas++;
                    if (numCommas > 1){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (numCommas == 1) {
                stringData.push_back(val.substr(0, val.find(',')));
                intData.push_back(stoi(val.substr(val.find(',') + 1, val.length() - 1)));
                cout << "Data string: " << val.substr(0, val.find(',')) << endl;
                cout << "Data integer: " << stoi(val.substr(val.find(',') + 1, val.length() - 1)) << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Error: Too many commas in input." << endl << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your first error is not posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you initialise `numCommas` to zero at the start of the program rather than at the start of each author input. That means, once it exceeds one, it will stay that high at least<sup>(a)</sup>, meaning future inputs will always be seen as having too many commas.

You just need to set it to zero immediately before checking *each* input.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Well, until it wraps around (if it wraps around). But that will be an *awful* lot of commas you need to input :-)

Comment: Are you suggesting a comma coma?